# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized, when DbContext is in another project, configured by root project

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, entity-framework-migrations

The idea of my application is to be divided in separate project for database access, and separate project for business logic. I've been struggling with good project organization in past couple of days. Then I found this article (https://medium.com/swlh/creating-a-multi-project-net-core-database-solution-a69decdf8d7e) which supports the idea mentioned above.

I have Data (class library) project, which has definition of DbContext, entities, entity configurations and so on. Also, there is `ServiceCollectionExtensions` static class for DbContext configuration and registering repositories.

My DbContext:

```
public class UserManagementDbContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
   public DbSet<UserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Module> Modules { get; set; }
   public DbSet<ModulePermission> ModulePermissions { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Data.Models.UserManagement.Action> Actions { get; set; }
   public DbSet<ISHTable> ISHTables { get; set; }
   public DbSet<ISHColumn> ISHColumns { get; set; }

   public UserManagementDbContext(DbContextOptions<UserManagementDbContext> options) : base(options) {}

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
     new ISHTableConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<ISHTable>());
     new ISHColumnConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<ISHColumn>());
     new UserConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<User>());
     new RoleConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Role>());
     new ModuleConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Module>());
     new ActionConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Data.Models.UserManagement.Action>());
     new AssociatedColumnConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<AssociatedColumn>());
     new ColumnPermissionConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<ColumnPermission>());
     new ModulePermissionConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<ModulePermission>());
     new UserRolesConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoles>());
     new LogConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Log>());
     new DMLActionConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<DMLAction>());
     new LanguageConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Language>());
     new PhraseConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Phrase>());
     new TranslationConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Translation>());
   }
}
```

Also, there is `ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs` static class

```
    public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection RegisterUserManagementDataServices(this IServiceCollection services, ConfigurationManager configuration)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<UserManagementDbContext>(o =>
            {
                o.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Main"));
                o.EnableDetailedErrors();
                o.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            });

            services.AddTransient(typeof(IGeneralRepository<>), typeof(GeneralRepository<>));
            services.AddTransient<IRolesRepository, RolesRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IActionsRepository, ActionsRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IISHColumnsRepository, ISHColumnsRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IISHTablesRepository, ISHTablesRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IUsersRepository, UsersRepository>();
            return services;
        }
    }
```

I have project reference from UserManagement WEB API Project to Data class library project, which Program.cs has the following line of code:

```
builder.Services.RegisterUserManagementDataServices(builder.Configuration);
```

My solution architecture looks like this:

[image: My Solution Explorer]

I ran Add-Migration Initial, with Default Project set to Data, everything went as expected, the migration was created. But, when I ran Update-Database, following error occurred:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized
```

And I'm stuck for a long time now. Any help would be very appreciated !

Comment: Put `Debugger.Launch()` in your program and execute `Update-Database`. You will be able to debug what is happened and what is not configured.

Comment: You may try to add an override of `OnConfiguring` in your DbContext to intialise the connection string for update command. example ` protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("constring");
        } `

Comment: @MukulKeshari I understand, but how I'm supposed to provide connection string from UserManagement project, we surely don't want it hardcoded.

Comment: When do you get this error? While run time or compile time? Could you please attach program.cs. In addition, what if you pass the empty constructor like this `public UserManagementDbContext(DbContextOptions<UserManagementDbContext > options) : base(options){}`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I use linked appsettings.json from Core project, and I actually have forgotten to add it to UserManagement's Program.cs. So, when I was passing the configuration to RegisterUserManagementDataServices, I was passing null. Now it works, as expected. Many thanks to you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You need an appsettings.json with the connection string in it inside your Data Project

Comment: Data project is class library. Connection string should be provided from external project I suppose ?

Comment: when running update-database from Data project it doesn't know about your UserManagement project

Comment: That was also my suspicion, but then, the article I read was buggy or not complete ?

Comment: add the appsettings and use something like this Update-Database -Verbose 
 -ConnectionString "CONNECTIONSTRING" 
 -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem, database is created. But then when sending http request to one of UserManagement's Controllers, the same problem occurs, that connection string is not initialized :(